# Can Google Analytics label countries without data on the map?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, visitors, geolocation, map

Looking at audience-geo-location I can view a map of the world by nation. I can mouse over the shaded nations from which 'sessions' arose to obtain a count and the name of the nation. However, for the grey nations (those without sessions) a mouse-over doesn't show the country name. The same would apply to U.S. states. It would be very good to have a list of these places so that I could make an effort there to attract visitors.

If not on the map view, is there a way to include places with no sessions in the list of places. Knowing where visitors are is nice but knowing about places without visitors is also important.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see a way of having that report show you those country names.  That might be a nice feature, but it isn't like the names of the countries of the world are a big secret.  Just search for "world country map" and have that open for cross reference to know what the grayed out countries are named.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a feature you can enable on GA per-say more a feature request to be made to Google which is outside the scope of this site. The easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do is to simply go to Google Maps and look at the area where GA reports no activity and then that will tell you the country and state to target. Involves some effort but is the only way to do it at the moment.